# Reading and updating Multi-Level elements in XML files in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have below  xml file I want to change  some of  attribute  that xml file using java code.
We  have changed  some attribute here  through   java code

Below Xml file  contains related information.

```
    <Order>
    <AllowedModifications>
    <Modification ModificationType="CHANGE_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES" ThroughOverride="Y"/>
    <Modification ModificationType="RECEIVING_NODE" ThroughOverride="Y"/>
    <Modification ModificationType="OTHERS" ThroughOverride="Y"/>
    </AllowedModifications>
    </Order>
```

Like if ModificationType=OTHERS then we have to change ThroughOverride value =Y. How  we can do it with the help of java code.

I tried below code but it is not changing.

```
    Element eleAllowedModifications = Util.getChildElement(eleOrderRoot,"AllowedModifications")
    System.out.println("First  Element "+eleAllowedModifications.getNodeName()); 
    Node staff = xmlFile.getElementsByTagName("Modification").item(0);
    NamedNodeMap attr = staff.getAttributes();
       for (int i = 0; i < attr.getLength(); i++) {
    Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("ModificationType");
    MoficationTYp =String.valueOf(nodeAttr);
    Node nodeAttr1= attr.getNamedItem("ThroughOverride");   
    MoficationTp =String.valueOf(nodeAttr);
    }

    if (MoficationTYp=="OTHERS") {
    for (int i = 0; i < attr.getLength(); i++) {
    Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("ThroughOverride");
    MoficationTYp =String.valueOf(nodeAttr);
    nodeAttr.setNodeValue("Y");                 
    }

    }
```

Here it is  not changing that value of ThroughOverride attribute .

Comment: anybody could  you tell me how we can do

Comment: Well, I wonder if it is a good idea (to say the least) to use `MoficationTYp=="OTHERS"`. Comparing String should be done with the `.equals()` method.

Comment: It's  also  not working i was  tried

Answer (score 0):

If you use an [XML library](http://xmlbeam.org) (Disclosure: I'm affiliated with that project), you can get your result with much less code:

```
public class UpdateOrder {

    public interface Order {
        @XBUpdate("//Modification[@ModificationType='OTHERS']/@ThroughOverride")
        void updateOrder(String value);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {    
        Order order = new XBProjector(Flags.TO_STRING_RENDERS_XML).io().url("res://data.xml").read(Order.class);
        order.updateOrder("N");
        System.out.println(order.toString());
    }

}
```

This program prints out:

```
<Order>
    <AllowedModifications>
        <Modification ModificationType="CHANGE_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES" ThroughOverride="Y"/>
        <Modification ModificationType="RECEIVING_NODE" ThroughOverride="Y"/>
        <Modification ModificationType="OTHERS" ThroughOverride="N"/>
    </AllowedModifications>
</Order>
```

Comment: not printing  output  it is giving java.net.MalformedURLException

Comment: @Cfx XMLBean seems to be an interesting library. I'll look a bit further soon, thanks for information.

Comment: The url protocol `res://` is used to load resources. Thus the xml file has to be in your classpath. You can use a valid file url or directly the file api: `projector.io.file("path").read(...)`.

Comment: but  it is was not changing value

Comment: Do you mean it does not write the change back to the file? Correct. That is up to you. Hint: `projector.io().file(...).write(order)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd rater use the following code (for example):

```
    Element eleAllowedModifications = Util.getChildElement(eleOrderRoot,"AllowedModifications");
    System.out.println("First  Element "+ eleAllowedModifications.getNodeName());
    Element staff = (Element)xmlFile.getElementsByTagName("Modification").item(0);
    moficationTyp = staff.getAttribute("ModificationType");
    //moficationTp = String.valueOf(nodeAttr);
    if (moficationTyp.equals("OTHERS")) {
       staff.setAttribute("ThroughOverride", "Y");
    }
```

Other comments:

- variable names (e.g. MoficationTYp ) should start with a lowercase letter.
- the loops are not useful here
- `String.valueOf()` does not seems appropriate to me here.